# vue validate input with regex add mask

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I have an input field that I validate `@blur`.

The goal is to allow 9 numbers grouped per 3 and a dot after, for example:

`123456789` this should be masked to `123.456.789`

But it should be possible too for the user to type `123.456.789` himself.

This is what I've got so far, I force the user to type `123.456.789`

```
<input
    @blur="validateNumber($event.target.value)"
>


validateNumber(value) {
  if (/^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$/.test(value)) {
     this.validNumber = true;
     return;
  } 

  this.validNumber = false;
  return;

}
```

I need a way to allow `123456789` and to make it `123.456.789`

Comment: Where would the dots be placed for 10, 11, and 12 digits?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It should always be 12 numbers grouped per 3 so always 3 numbers then a dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OR operator `|` to add the numeric-only check to your existing pattern

```
(^\d{9}$)|(^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$)
```

Or make it more readable with two separate checks

```
if (/^\d{9}$/.test(value) || /^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$/.test(value))
```

To add the mask separate the checks and modify the value if it is numeric, something like:

```
<input v-model="number" @blur="validateNumber">

data() {
  return {
    valid: false,
    number: "",
  };
},
methods: {
  validateNumber() {
    if (/^\d{9}$/.test(this.number)) {
      this.number = this.number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1.$2.$3");
      this.valid = true;
    } else if (/^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{3}$/.test(this.number)) {
      this.valid = true;
    } else {
      this.valid = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, if they type 123456789 it needs to be masked as 123.456.789 and if they type 123.456.789 it should be okay. I miss here how to add the dots after a group of 3 characters

Comment: I added a way you can mask it when the value is numeric